# Getting Top N items per group in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.6.2, I have the following data structure:

```
sample = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
                    (1,['potato','orange','orange']),
                    (1,['potato','orange','yogurt']),
                    (2,['vodka','beer','vodka']),
                    (2,['vodka','beer','juice', 'vinegar'])

    ],['cat','terms'])
```

I would like to extract top N most frequent terms per cat. I have developed the following solution which seems to work, however I wanted to see if there is a better way to do this.

```
from collections import Counter
def get_top(it, terms=200):
    c = Counter(it.__iter__())
    return [x[0][1] for x in c.most_common(terms)]

( sample.select('cat',sf.explode('terms')).rdd.map(lambda x: (x.cat, x.col))
 .groupBy(lambda x: x[0])
 .map(lambda x: (x[0], get_top(x[1], 2)))
 .collect()
)
```

It provides the following output:

```
[(1, ['orange', 'potato']), (2, ['vodka', 'beer'])]
```

Which is in line with what I am looking for, but I really don't like the fact that I am resorting to using Counter. How can I do it with spark alone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is working it is probably better to post this to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Just as an exercise I did this without the Counter but largely you are just replicating the same functionality.

- Count each occurrence of (`cat`, `term`)
- Group by `cat`
- Sort the values based on Count and slice to number of terms (`2`)

Code:

```
from operator import add

(sample.select('cat', sf.explode('terms'))
 .rdd
 .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
 .reduceByKey(add)
 .groupBy(lambda x: x[0][0])
 .mapValues(lambda x: [r[1] for r, _ in sorted(x, key=lambda a: -a[1])[:2]])
 .collect())
```

Output:

```
[(1, ['orange', 'potato']), (2, ['vodka', 'beer'])]
```

Comment: Nice. I had most of this up until mapValues, couldn't figure that one out. Thanks!

Comment: It can be a challenge keeping track of the scaffolding structures, to extract the data back out.